# Can I refactor to Model View Query Handler?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, architecture, cqrs

In our MVC application all of our read actions as a paramter take a query which implements:

```
public interface IQuery<out TResponse> { }
```

Within the action the query is passed to a bus which locates a handler and returns a view model. So controllers now look something like this:

```
   public ActionResult Edit(DetailsQuery query)
    {
        var model = mediator.Request(query);
        return View(model);
    }
```

Effectively just passing queries to our mediator and returning the result. We have hundreds of actions that look like this. There is the odd action that does something conditional (which I would leave as they are) but the rest are just the same boilerplate again and again. We have over hundred different queries

How can I refactor this to something more explicit?  I guess moving to a Model View Query Handler rather than the boilerplate controller action that just hands off query to the bus and returns model to View.

What extension points should I look at in MVC? Effectively instead of having to write the action handler - just have some automatic way of wiring together strongly typed query and getting back the correct ViewModel.

If I can? Should I? I just don't like seeing hundreds of actions that all look the same.

Comment: how many different query types do you have? and how is your request beign mapped to the specific query type

Comment: We have hundred or so queries. If it isn't a single id parameter it is generally encapsulated within a query. Basically we are doing same thing as this http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/10/29/put-your-controllers-on-a-diet-gets-and-queries/

Comment: If you do have a single parameter, do you still use a mediator.Request call to get the view model?

Comment: Generally for straight one parameter query it is probably going straight to a repository. So just pass to that and then Automap to a ViewModel

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, thanks for the link to the post ["Put your controllers on a diet: GETs and queries"](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2013/10/29/put-your-controllers-on-a-diet-gets-and-queries/). My code example uses types from it.

My solution **also involves usage of action filters** as point to inject generic behaviour.

Controller is simple enough and looks like @Kambiz Shahim's:

```
[QueryFilter]
public class ConferenceController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index(IndexQuery query)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ViewResult Show(ShowQuery query)
    {
        return View();
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(EditQuery query)
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

Working on `QueryFilterAttribute` I realised that **`IMediator` and its implementation can be omitted. It is enough to know type of query to resolve an instance of `IQueryHandler<,>` via IoC.**

In my example [Castle Windsor](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx) and implementation of ['Service Locator'](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/) pattern are used.

```
public class QueryFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        object query = filterContext.ActionParameters["query"];
        Type queryType = query.GetType();
        Type modelType = queryType.GetInterfaces()[0].GetGenericArguments()[0];

        var handlerType = typeof(IQueryHandler<,>).MakeGenericType(queryType, modelType);

        // Here you should resolve your IQueryHandler<,> using IoC
        // 'Service Locator' pattern is used as quick-and-dirty solution to show that code works.
        var handler = ComponentLocator.GetComponent(handlerType) as IQueryHandler;

        var model = handler.Handle(query);
        filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
    }
}
```

`IQueryHandler` interface is added to avoid working with Reflection

```
/// <summary>
/// All derived handlers can be refactored using generics. But in the real world handling logic can be completely different.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TQuery">The type of the query.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TResponse">The type of the response.</typeparam>
public interface IQueryHandler<in TQuery, out TResponse> : IQueryHandler
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResponse>
{
    TResponse Handle(TQuery query);
}

/// <summary>
/// This interface is used in order to invoke 'Handle' for any query type.
/// </summary>
public interface IQueryHandler
{
    object Handle(object query);
}

/// <summary>
/// Implements 'Handle' of 'IQueryHandler' interface explicitly to restrict its invocation.
/// </summary>
/// <typeparam name="TQuery">The type of the query.</typeparam>
/// <typeparam name="TResponse">The type of the response.</typeparam>
public abstract class QueryHandlerBase<TQuery, TResponse> : IQueryHandler<TQuery, TResponse>
    where TQuery : IQuery<TResponse>
{
    public abstract TResponse Handle(TQuery query);

    object IQueryHandler.Handle(object query)
    {
        return Handle((TQuery)query);
    }
}
```

Types should be registered `in Global.asax.cs`

```
        container.Register(Component.For<ISession>().ImplementedBy<FakeSession>());
        container.Register(
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn(typeof(IQueryHandler<,>))
                .WithService.Base()
                .LifestylePerWebRequest());
```

There is a [**link to gist on github**](https://gist.github.com/ilyapalkin/c82904208bd529814713) with all code.

Comment: Yeah does make it easier to just remove the mediator.

Comment: Though, this results in Service Locator anti-pattern as unit testing you would have no idea what the controller and their methods actually depend on.

Comment: There might be a way to replace static Service Locator with a registry and pass it as a dependency. It's a good option that doesn't work well with attributes in C#

Answer (score 4):

Sounds to me like you want a custom [ControllerActionInvoker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controlleractioninvoker%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) e.g.

```
public class ReadControllerActionInvoker : ControllerActionInvoker
{
    private IMediator mediator;

    public ReadControllerActionInvoker(IMediator mediator)
    {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    protected override ActionResult CreateActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, object actionReturnValue)
    {
        ViewDataDictionary model = null;

        // get our query parameter
        var query = GetParameterValue(controllerContext, actionDescriptor.GetParameters().Where(x => x.ParameterName == "query").FirstOrDefault());

        // pass the query to our mediator
        if (query is DetailsQuery)
            model = new ViewDataDictionary(this.mediator.Request((DetailsQuery)query));

        // return the view with read model returned from mediator
        return new ViewResult
        {
            ViewName = actionDescriptor.ActionName,
            ViewData = model
        };
    }
}
```

We then introduce a base controller where we inject our custom `ControllerActionInvoker`

```
public class BaseReadController : Controller
{
    protected IMediator Mediator { get; set; }

    protected override void Initialize(System.Web.Routing.RequestContext requestContext)
    {
        base.Initialize(requestContext);
        ActionInvoker = new ReadControllerActionInvoker(Mediator);
    }
}
```

Then finally in our controller, we derive from our base and return the query information from our actions e.g.

```
public class QueryController : BaseReadController
{
    // our actions now do nothing but define a route for our queries
    public void About(DetailsQuery query)
    {
    }
}
```

What you effectively end up with here is bodiless actions so you lose the repetitive code but, in my opinion, you sacrifice some readability (there is a lot of voodoo happening in the controller now which isn't immediately obvious).

Comment: Sounds interesting, any further advice?

Comment: @GraemeMiller here's an [interesting article](http://weblogs.asp.net/nmarun/archive/2011/02/26/asp-net-mvc-extendable-hooks-controlleractioninvoker-class.aspx) on how you can use it to intercept/control the output for your controller actions. The way I see it, you would end up with a very anaemic controller with nothing but action definitions e.g. `public void Edit(DetailsQuery query) { }` with the mediation stuff sitting in the custom invoker. If I get some time I will try put an example together but if you walk through the article you should find it relatively straightforward.

Comment: We moved all our logic into queries so was trying to keep the controller as really just a layer over the queries and commands. Make it as thin as possible and really just responsible for coordinating.

Comment: That looks great. Will give it a try later tonight. Really appreciate it

Comment: That is what I pictured - I am still finishing work on our latest iteration which ends today so not had a chance to implement. Any idea how I can handle the fact that I have lots of queries of different classes that all implement the interface IQuery<>. DetailsQuery is just one of hundreds. Guess I need to add some sort of generics and casting

Comment: Think I've got it now.

Comment: @GraemeMiller sounds like you just want a generic query class i.e. `Query<T> : IQuery<T>`

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is to create an `ActionFilter` to decorate the actions in the controllers like this:

```
    [GenericActionFilter(ModelType=typeof(ShowModel))]
    public ActionResult Edit(ShowQuery query)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

and this is the `ActionFilter`

```
public class GenericActionFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public Type ModelType { get; set; }
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

        IMediator mediator = null;
        if(filterContext.Controller is BaseController)
        {
            mediator = ((BaseController)filterContext.Controller).GetMediator();
            object paramValue = filterContext.ActionParameters["query"];
            var method = mediator.GetType().GetMethod("Request").MakeGenericMethod(new Type[] { ModelType });
            var model = method.Invoke(mediator, new object[] { paramValue });
            filterContext.Controller.ViewData.Model = model;
        }
    }

}
```

and the `BaseController`

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    private readonly IMediator mediator;

    public BaseController():this(new Mediator())
    {

    }

    public BaseController(IMediator mediator)
    {
        this.mediator = mediator;
    }

    public IMediator GetMediator()
    {
        return mediator;
    }
}
```

this is based on an assumption which the `Request` method of the `Mediator` is a generic method like this:

```
public interface IMediator
{
    TResponse Request<TResponse>(IQuery<TResponse> query);
}
```

and

```
public class ShowQuery  : IQuery<ShowModel>
{
    public string EventName { get; set; }
}
```